# SQL query not getting results with multiple ANDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a SQL query to get data from my MySQL database:

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.time, wp_users.display_name 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%user%' 
AND wp_users.time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) 
ORDER BY wp_users.display_name";
```

It is getting a list of all users without the second AND statement:

```
AND wp_users.time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE))
```

Is there anything I can do to have two ANDs to make it working?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What's stored in the `time` column? (logically)

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko it has got UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Comment: What type does `wp_users.time` column have? Please, show some examples of values from this table.

Comment: What if you remove the first "AND" condition? Are you getting any data? Are you sure there actually *is* data in your table that fullfills all the conditions? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: @AlexeyShein wp_users.time has got a timestamp "1442310742"

Comment: Then everything should be correct. Maybe it's just there is not data that obeys these conditions? Try to make this query a bit broader, for example, put `1 HOUR` instead of `1 MINUTE`.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko when I remove - INNER JOIN alkp_usermeta ON alkp_users.ID = alkp_usermeta.user_id WHERE alkp_usermeta.meta_key = 'alkp_capabilities' AND alkp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%user%'  It works ok but without filtering from a second table

Comment: @AlexeyShein I changed to 1 HOUR but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an error with the query.  I think the error is an artefact of your data set.  From the comments on your question, I understand that the original query:

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.time, wp_users.display_name 
FROM wp_users 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%user%' 
AND wp_users.time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) 
ORDER BY wp_users.display_name";
```

returns no results, but that removing the inner join and join conditions:

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.time, wp_users.display_name 
FROM wp_users 
WHERE wp_users.time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) 
ORDER BY wp_users.display_name";
```

produces what you were expecting.  This implies that:

1. there are users whose wp_users.time is within the target interval, but
2. these users don't have corresponding entries in the wp_usermeta table and
3. there are other users who do have corresponding entries, but they don't match the wp_users.time interval

Inner joins require matching key entries:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

I think your choices are:

1. alter the data set so that 100% of users participate in the wp_usermeta table
2. convert the inner join to a left join or full outer join and relax the where constraints, e.g.:

   `SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.time, wp_users.display_name 
   FROM wp_users 
   LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
   ON wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
   AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%user%' 
   WHERE wp_users.time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) 
   ORDER BY wp_users.display_name;`

That will technically make it work, but your query will be accepting users who only have NULLs for the corresponding (non-participating) wp_usermeta entries.